# Maven Profile with different config files

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

**my project structure** looks like this

```
-src/main/java
-src/main/resources
 -dev
  -app.properties
 -prod
  -app.properties
 -sandbox
   -app.properties
```

and I **defined a maven profiles** like this

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile>dev</build.profile>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile>prod</build.profile>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>sandbox</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile>sandbox</build.profile>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/sandbox</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

**what I am trying to do** is to copy the right property from the right sub folder, when I triggered the right profile, e.g *mvn -pdev install*. will let the maven copy the *app.properties* file from the *src/main/resource/dev* folder then place into the jar I am building

my jar looks like this:

```
  +dev
  +prod
  +sandbox
  +META-INF
  +com
  -app.properties
```

**the problem is** 5 folders with a single properties file, I don't want the dev prod sandbox folders.

Comment: do you want this file into the root of your jar or in the dev/prod/sandbox subfolder?

Comment: What do you mean with other sub folders? Do you have the folders dev, prod, sandbox in your JAR, or subfolders within the folder for the profile? Could you post a sample, how your JAR looks?

Comment: @SergeyPauk in the root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dunni's answer will work but I did this way

1. putting the sub folders into a folder called src/main/profiles, if you are using eclipse, its important to add this folder as "source folder".
   so the project looks like this

   -src/main/resource

   -src/main/profiles

   ```
   -prod
   -dev 
   -ist
   ```

Note : you can put anything where is common and never changes cross all profiles into the resource folder, etc log4j.properties
then put the profile specific ones into each sub folders respectively.

and the final profile section looks like this

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile>dev</build.profile>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/profiles/dev</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile>prod</build.profile>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/profiles/prod</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>sandbox</id>
      <properties>
        <build.profile>sandbox</build.profile>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/profiles/sandbox</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

reason I did this way is because Maven by default is trying to copy everything from the /resource folder into the jar.

but using the jar plugin I can get what I want, but I am trying to keep my
pom simple.

the main problem I have faced there, is **how to excluding files from the /resource folder**. please comment if anyone knows better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a plugin which isn't respecting the resource entries in the build section and using src/main/resources as resource folder. In that case i would change the folder structure like this:

```
src  
 - main  
  - resources-dev
  - resources-prod
  - resources-sandbox
```

and change the folder names in the build sections. This way you don't interfere with the standard maven folder structure.

Comment: this will work. but I prefe to put all the sub folders into a single folder e.g src/main/profiles

Comment: Sure, that's also possible. Just don't use the standard src/main/resources folder.